# Validate if row exist, if not insert - MYSQL TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a script that allows me to detect if the inserted record already exists in the database, it is assumed that the script runs, but when it detects that this script exists for the entire insertion loop and does not proceed with the following ones that may not be duplicated.

How can I do so that the script does not stop and continue reviewing the next inserted data, since it does not detect that one is duplicated, it stops and does not allow to check if the following ones are not

```
BEGIN
DECLARE registro INT;

set registro = (select count(*) from Leads 
                WHERE nombres = NEW.nombres and 
                      apellidos = NEW.apellidos and 
                      n_documento = NEW.n_documento and 
                      programa = NEW.programa);

IF(registro > 0) THEN
INSERT INTO Leads VALUES (
null, 
new.nombres, 
new.apellidos, 
new.n_documento, 
new.fecha_de_nacimiento, 
new.telefono, 
new.email, 
new.ciudad,
new.pais, 
new.anos_de_experiencia,
new.origen,
new.informacion_adicional,
new.fecha,
new.programa,
new.estado,
new.fecha_charla,
new.grado_de_estudio,
new.empresa,
new.cargo,
null
);
END IF;
```

Comment: A trigger for this is really heavy handed. Why not just insert and deal with the potential error, or `INSERT IGNORE`, or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` to handle a collision.

Comment: @tadman dou u have a example please?

Comment: It's all [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) if you [search for the right things](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: @BryanRivera do you have `UNIQUE` or composite Primary Key defined on `(nombres, apellidos, n_documento, programa)` ?